# Using Android Storage Access Framework and direct file access together

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-5.0-lollipop, documentfile

I have an app that extensively uses file system including external SD card.

Currently it uses File APIs to create/delete/list files but I would like to use new Android Storage Access Framework.

Issue is that almost 60% of install base is still on JB and below and I need new [Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67570#c4444). I am not quite sure how to go about implementing it.

I thought I would write a common interface to use in my app something like MyFile then use appropriate APIs according to platform version but it will be too much unless there is already a library that does it.

What other people are doing?How do you manage this situation?

Comment: I hope this library can help you _https://github.com/bartwell/ExFilePicker_

Comment: See [android-simple-storage](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-storage) and [G-Rex](https://github.com/Naturally-Being/G-Rex)

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage

Answer (score 0):

Make some abstraction of your operations.

If you use `File` in many places, first replace it by some abstract class of interface such as `FileSystem`, providing same functionality as `File`, but hiding implementation details. All work with File has to be removed and placed in just one implementation of your TheFile interface, named for example `NativeFileSystem`. Implement all needed functions, such as open/delete/rename/create.

Use factory function to create `FileSystem` for example in your Application class. This is place where you later make decision what is actual class created for the work.

When you test that you hid implementation details and your app works, you can create new implementation named for example `SAFFileSystem`, and implement needed functions, but in a way how Storage Access Framework allows.

Be prepared that some methods that can be run on File on main thread will probably be asynchronous. This is because SAF may possibly show dialog and ask user for confirmation. So there may be some rework in your app related to method calls.

Hope that helps.

Comment: since everybody has this problem, perhaps somebody already has implemented this very abstraction that others can use?